# Developing probability distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, bayesian, binomial-distribution

An event occurs, and after this event has occurred there is a set of conclusions which can be drawn. All of these conclusions have results which are distinct. I am trying to keep this as general as possible but as an example, this is similar to two players playing a game of rock-paper-scissors, and after this game has happened, you can say each player's move was one of $\{\text{rock, paper, scissors}\}$, and that the outcome of the game was one of $\{\text{player1 win, player2 win}\}$. You can also say things like there were $\text{x}$ draws before a winner was found, where $\text{x} \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} = \mathbb{N}_0$. The set of results of these conclusions can be assumed to be finite or countably infinite.

Before the event occurs, there is a set of perceived probabilities relating to these conclusions. We are given no information about how these probabilities are calculated, we are simply given a probability. Relating this back to our example of rock-paper-scissors we may be given something such as $\text{P(result = player1 win)} = 0.4$, or statements such as $\text{P(draws before winner found < 3)} = 0.6$.

Now what I want to do is see if there is any statistical link between some of these perceived probabilities, and some of the conclusions which can be drawn. I would then want to proceed to develop a probability model to predict some of these conclusions based on the perceived probabilities.

I really don't know where to even start with this. I have a data set which has information regarding around 10,000 events. I'm not sure if using a Bayesian approach is appropriate due to the fact that we don't know any information about the distributions of the perceived probabilities. So if anyone could give me some pointers regarding what topics would be good to look into, or in fact clarify for me what question I am actually trying to ask here, that would be fantastic.

Comment: A Bayesian approach might be fine, but doesn't appear necessary. These are just binomial variables.

Answer (score 1):

A Bayesian approach might be fine, but doesn't appear necessary. These are just [binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) variables.  Inside your probability statements (e.g., "$P(\rm result = player1\ win)=0.4$") is a statement that can be converted into $\rm TRUE$ or $\rm FALSE$ for each of the events in your dataset.  So you can get the proportion true and test it against your null hypothesis with a [binomial test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test).